# How can I set LightningChart's Y axis to right edge of the graph

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, charts, axis

In [LightningChart](http://www.LightningChart.com)'s ViewXY, I have two Y axes, probably more a little bit later. The axes are shown in the left side of the chart. Is there an option to move the second axis to the right?

I tried to set the axis.Position = 100 but it didn't move the axis. I'm using LightningChart v.7.

See picture:
[Axis should be moved like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMFWZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by setting

```
chart.ViewXY.AxisLayout.YAxisAutoPlacement = LeftThenRight.
```